# Codeigniter URLs being redirected or extra part is added to URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a strange problem. Everything was working fine untill yesterday and suddenly just noticed this problem.

The webiste is here:
http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/all_trips

If you visit above page and click on "india-kerala" link, it should take you to the following page.

http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/trips/old_trips/india_kerala

However the browser redirects to this page:
http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/all_trips/old_trips/india_kerala?/trips/old_trips/india_kerala
This indicates that the following part was added that is extra.
all_trips/old_trips/india_kerala?

I checked my .htaaccess and reset it to defaultbut it still doesn't affect it. I checked my cofnig.php for base url and everything is same as before. If anyone can help, I will appriciate.

my .htaccess file

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]  

Redirect 301 /invest.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/investment_opportunity
Redirect 301 /buyers.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/buyers
Redirect 301 /trips.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/all_trips
Redirect 301 /sellers.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/sellers
Redirect 301 /contact.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/contact_us
Redirect 301 /about.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/about_us
Redirect 301 /login.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/login
Redirect 301 /trip-kerala.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/trips/old_trips/india_kerala
Redirect 301 /trip-burundi.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/trips/up_coming_trips/burundi_africa
Redirect 301 /register.php http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/register
Redirect 301 /trips http://www.famtripsandinspectionvisits.com/all_trips
```

My routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['fam_admin'] = "fam_admin/login";
/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

Kind regards

Comment: Both adresses return 404 right now? Maybe it's the reason? Try to make the path work in your controllers to avoid the 404 and tell us if it gets working?

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` and `routes.php` file?

Comment: I think the probem is to do with the redirection or somewhere the extra part in the url is being added not sure from where this is being added.

Comment: I have added the .htaccess and router.php file in now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Probably the last redirect rule is redirecting `trips/old_trips/india_kerala` to `all_trips/old_trips/india_kerala`

Comment: Yes, found it. The last line in .htaccess was causing it. Another thing was that firefox was caching files and was giving same result even when I cleared emptied the .htaccess file. So I cleared the cache of firefox and removed the last line of .htaccess file and everything is working as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do here is tell mod_rewrite that you want to combine the new and old query strings, which requires the use of the QSA flag:

```
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

That is my 'standard' base set of rules for my Codeigniter projects, the rest I accomplish much as you have with custom routes and the occasional redirect.

Ending the substitution with just a question mark (in the absence of the QSA flag) will erase the existing query string and replace it with the new one, which I think explains what you're seeing.

The [documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) gets a bit more in depth when it comes to this:

> Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string
>   to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old
>   query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue. try editing you `config.php` to look look like this:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
```

I am assuming you are using one of CodeIgniter's URL methods and you are (assuming) using IIS to host. I don't know how to remove the '?' between the URL and the query string but adding the '?' to your config file should resolve the links at least.

Comment: What led you to believe that he's using IIS?

Comment: I am assuming he is using IIS. I had this same issue with one of my sites that was running on IIS and adding the `?` resolved my issue.